# Visual Studio - Cursor offset?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to place an object to my cursor location, but there is a giant offset?
**Why?**

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (moving == true)
    {
        panel1.Location = Cursor.Position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code samples speak louder than words :)

Comment: the offset is probably absolute to the desktop, and not relative to your window. But this is a crazy guess as you've given very little information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) is "the cursor's position in screen coordinates". Use the [MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx), as shown in this [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201286/get-cursor-position-with-respect-to-the-control-c-sharp)