# mouse position (Cursor.Position)

Tags: c#, image, mouseevent, picturebox, pixel

I have image 10*10 mult it in factor and loading the image to picturebox I have problem to select the mouse position when I clicking in everywhere over the image the point showing in the corner Upper-left what is the error??

Comment: have you tried doing a google search on the following `PointToClient(Cursor.Position)` 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201286/get-cursor-position-with-respect-to-the-control-c-sharp  also I would think that you would want to do this on the Mouse Click event hot the Image Click Event

Comment: I'm using  pictureBox click event (pb1_Click)

Comment: Us the `MouseClick` event instead. Its params have the coordinates (relative to the `PB.ClientSize`)

Comment: @TaW  I'm using MouseClick but the same problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw into a **zoomed** `Image` of a `PictureBox` this works fine for me:

```
float zoom = 7.5f;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pb1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    pb1.ClientSize = new Size((int) (pb1.Image.Size.Width  * zoom), 
                              (int) (pb1.Image.Size.Height * zoom) );
}



private void pb1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   int x = (int)Math.Round(e.X / zoom) ;
   int y = (int)Math.Round(e.Y / zoom) ;
   Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) pb1.Image;
   bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
   pb1.Refresh();
}
```

Note: This works equally well if the `PictureBox` is sitting in an `AutoScroll Panel`.

[image][image]

Comment: thank for answer ,please if you can see my update ,I have this error NullReferenceexception...

Comment: Where do you get the exception? The code assumes the pb1.Image is loaded (from the start.) I don't see the zoom variable, but it wouldn't throw an exception but a compiler error..

Comment: zoom variable I use it in my code but here not :(  but the same error NullReferenceexception....

Comment: Where?????????? Note: you can set the `pb1.ClientSize` only __after__ setting the `Image` !!  (Also note the improved calculation!)

Comment: here and same  the error pb1.ClientSize = new Size((int) (pb1.Image.Size.Width * zoom), (int) (pb1.Image.Size.Height * zoom) ); ,I'm work on the code in question

Comment: I thought so. Make sure the size is __always and only__ set __after__ the Image is set!

Comment: The solution is very simple: __Move__ the line in question to the spot in the `button1_Click` I have marked as `//***`  - My test program sets the image in the designer; I should have noticed that you use a dialog to set it. Sorry!