# C# OnDrag + Mouse Right Click

Tags: c#

Is it possible to detect a right-mouse click while dragging a picture across the win form and if it possible how would I need to do it?

I tried doing this:

```
battleBoard[outLoop, inLoop].Tag = outLoop.ToString() + "," + inLoop.ToString();
battleBoard[outLoop, inLoop].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(boardEnter);
battleBoard[outLoop, inLoop].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(boardLeave);
battleBoard[outLoop, inLoop].DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(boardDragE);
battleBoard[outLoop, inLoop].DragLeave += new EventHandler(boardDragL);
battleBoard[outLoop, inLoop].DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(boardDragD);
battleBoard[outLoop, inLoop].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(boardClicked);
```

But still the click event does not trigger while I am dragging a picture. I hope that someone can assist me with my problem. Thanks.

Comment: No, Sir. I am not using WPF.

Comment: I __think__ the dragging operation captures the mouse and won't let any mouseevents of yours be triggered in the meantime.

Comment: Oh. I guess I'll have to think of another way of implementing the code. Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: You could [Get cursor position with respect to the control - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201286/get-cursor-position-with-respect-to-the-control-c-sharp) to know if entered the other control or not